# Replacing specific colors with black using slicing?

Tags: python, replace, colors, slice, pixel

first time asking a question on stackoverflow!
I'm trying to replace specific pixel colors using slicing. I'm interested in replacing the color pink with black.

```
 colors = [(0, 0, 0), (255, 0, 255)]
 img = cv2.imread('Untitled.png')  # Random image containing some pink pixels
 pink = img[:, :, :] == np.array(colors[1])  # Boolean array with TRUE @ all pink indices
```

When I attempt to replace using this function

```
img[pink, :] = np.array(colors[0])  # Replace with black
```

I get the following error

```
img[pink, :] = np.array(colors[0])
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

img and pink are same dimensions and sizes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('test.png')
image[np.where((image==[255,0,255]).all(axis=2))] = [0,0,0]
cv2.imwrite('test_out.png', image)
```

Comment: Thank you, it does! Does (image==[255, 0, 255]).all(axis=2) mean it looks at the x and y axis?